# How to configure Tomcat7 server.xml Environment to take as value Network path?

Tags: configuration, network-share, tomcat7

I am trying to configure Tomcat7 serer.xml
the

```
<Host appBase="webapps/testweb" name="trythis.test.com" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context docBase="." path="" reloadable="false">
       <Environment name="WEB_APP_PROPERTIES" type="java.lang.String" value="\\10.120.13.200\config"/>
    </Context>
</Host>
```

Even though this config folder is accessible over the network my Tomcat can't access it:

[image]

Did I configure Environment wrongly?